# PHP Add array and loop to code

Tags: php

I have a class which is working fine but I need to do multiple results.

Here is the current code:

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com';
$keyword = 'somekeyword';

$RankChecker=new RankChecker(1,5);

$result=$RankChecker->find($url,$keyword);

if ($result!==false) {

    echo "Your website is found at page number  ".$result["page"].".";

}
```

What is the best way to get it to read multiple url's / keyword's ?

Comment: What's `RankChecker`?

Comment: show what you have, and what you want (result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the URLs and keywords into an array and loop through it:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://mydomain.com' => 'somekeyword',
    'http://myotherdomain.com' => 'someotherkeyword'
);

$RankChecker=new RankChecker(1,5);

foreach($urls as $url => $keyword) {
    $result=$RankChecker->find($url,$keyword);

    if ($result!==false) {

        echo "Website " . $url . " is found at page number  ".$result["page"].".";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an array :

```
<?php

$websites[1] = array('url' => 'http://mydomain.com', 'keyword' => 'somekeyword');
$websites[2] = array('url' => 'http://mydomain2.com', 'keyword' => 'somekeyword2');
$websites[3] = array('url' => 'http://mydomain3.com', 'keyword' => 'somekeyword3');
// etc...

foreach ($websites as $val) 
{
    $RankChecker=new RankChecker(1,5);

    $result=$RankChecker->find($val['url'], $val['keyword']);

    if ($result!==false) {

        echo "Your website is found at page number  ".$result["page"].".";

    }   
}
```